# Create Git feature branch from another feature branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

Is there a way in Git to create a Git feature branch (B) from another feature branch (A) but do not keep history from (A) and only display history of changes in B when create a PR?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that, the commits in branch (A) would have to already be in the branch that you are performing the PR against.  Essentially branch (A) already needs to have a completed PR for it's commits, otherwise you will including commits from both branches in your PR.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create a PR into master, then you're going to have all the commits from A and B.

You can change B's base to master with the following command:

`git rebase --onto master A B`

The better solution is to just not branch off a feature branch if you don't really want the changes from that feature branch.

Comment: The problem is that A hasn't been merged with master yet... But B is a different feature that needs changes made in A...

Comment: This will effectively remove all the commits that are only in A from B.
EDIT: I see what you're saying. This smells like bad process. There's no good way to get around this issue. I'd just wait until A is merged.